# drawing the game board in Haskell - problem

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to build the board for the Peg Solitaire game but I'm stuck. I hope you can help me. The following code runs and generates a square of 3 on 3 circles. How could I make 3 more such squares but put them in other positions? I use the Gloss library

```
module Main(main) where

import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Data.ViewPort
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game
import Data.List

width, height, offset :: Int
width = 400
height = 400
offset = 100

window :: Display
window = InWindow "Peg Solitaire" (width, height) (offset, offset)

background :: Color
background = white

drawing :: Picture
drawing = Pictures [ (translate (x * 40) (y * 40) $ circleSolid 12)| x<-[-1..1], y<-[2..4] ]

main = display window background drawing
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your graphic library, but apparently you can use a [list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) and pass it to the `Pictures` constructor.

So it is just a matter of writing the appropriate list comprehension expression.

The expression you give can be rewritten as:

```
drawing1 = let circles1 = [ (translate (x1 * 40) (y1 * 40) $ circleSolid 12)  |
                            x1 <- [-1..1], y1 <- [2..4]   ]  in  Pictures circles1
```

If you would like to arrange your 3+1=4 circle groups into a regular grid, you can introduce extra loop levels, say with variables x0 and y0, like this:

```
drawing2 = let circles2 = [ (translate (x0*200 + x1*40) (y0*200 + y1*40)
                           $ circleSolid 12)                     |
                                  x0 <- [0,1]  , y0 <- [0,1],
                                  x1 <- [-1..1], y1 <- [2..4]    ]
           in  Pictures circles2
```

If you prefer to arrange the circle groups in arbitrary fashion, you can introduce one extra loop variable, say `cg` which is to run over the main coordinates of the circle groups:

```
circleGroups = [ (0,0), (0,200), (200,0), (200,200) ]  -- list of (x,y) pairs
drawing3 = let circles3 = [
                 translate ((fst cg)*200 + x1*40) ((snd cg)*200 + y1*40)
                               $ circleSolid 12                 |
                                   cg <- circleGroups,
                                   x1 <- [-1..1], y1 <- [2..4]  ]

           in  Pictures circles3
```

**Note:** Please please limit your source code to about 80 characters per line, so we don't have to use the horizontal slider. This is really a massive hindrance to code readability. Thanks.